# Is there a web-kit or gecko based Webbrowser library on wp7?

Tags: browser, windows-phone-7

The original browser doesn't support css3 and HTML5,It even cannot display jQuery Mobile demo and Ckeditor.Is there any replacement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an update (codename Mango) on the way to bring IE9 and its new Javascript compiler to Windows Phone 7. IE9 is an implementation of HTML5/CSS3. I have not special knowledge but the rumors on the web:
http://gizmodo.com/5724937/windows-phone-7-rumored-updates-copy--paste-ie9-html5-and-silverlight-coming

Comment: Microsoft always release uncompleted software and followed a dozen of patch.Thanks for you knowledge

Answer (score 1):

wp7 still runs IE7 which was made when HTML5 and CSS3 were not even though about!.

You could check out Opera Mobile as of now.
for jQuery mobile demo, you could refer browser support here: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

cheers

Comment: Thanks,But it is sad that I can't use opera within my application.Does Microsoft planned to run ie9 in wp7?

Comment: Microsoft hasn't made any official statements, but one must assume that future versions of the phone software will contain incremental improvements.  E.g. Silverlight 4, later versions of IE, etc.  At least, that is what I hope!